# What is the action called when a grumpy old man shows that he is annoyed, by making a 'throat-clearing' sound?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, idioms

Sometimes when a grumpy old man gets annoyed, he makes noises like clearing his throat. Does grumbling or grunting define that action? Is there a more appropriate word or an idiom for that?

Comment: Ahem.  We say "grumpy old man" since judgments usually come first in a string of adjectives.  Beautiful green dress versus green beautiful dress.

Comment: You'd have to ask my wife what she calls what I'm doing just before she elbows me in the ribs.

Comment: Does this question need to be ageist and sexist? "Harrumphing" isn't limited to either group...

Comment: @TimRomano Do you have a source for that?  I never considered why that is the way it is.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Sometimes when a grumpy old man gets annoyed, he makes noises like clearing his throat. Does grumbling or grunting define that action?*

Grumble:

- definitely not.  That consists of complaining words, it is not a sound.

Grunt:

- close, but that isn't it.  Grunt doesn't include throat-clearing, and it is an inhalation.

> *Is there a more appropriate word or an idiom for that?*

Yes.

**Growl**.

- Done properly, it is deep in the throat.
- The best *growl* is accomplished with the mouth closed, as a harsh exhalation, through the nose only.  No work is done in the nose, all the work is in the lower throat, vibrating it.  The deeper the better.
- A poor *growl* is high in the throat, see *harrumph* below.
- A *growl* is a purposeful act, not due to accident or sickness.
- Young men used to be able to do it.

*Grunt*

- is high in the throat, and can be accomplished almost completely in the nose and mouth, that is, without involving the throat.  The best *grunt* is actually a heavy inhalation, with the nostrils and the back of the mouth loose, so that it vibrates with the air flow.
- Animals *grunt* and *growl*.

*Harrumph*

- is close, but distinctly different, it doesn't have that full throat-clearing sound that men can make, from deep in their throats.
- I would describe *harrumph* as an amateur or beginner *growl*.  It is more of a sound of displeasure, whereas *growl* is a serious threat.

*Wheeze*

- has a proper meaning, the sound a person makes when they have emphysema, or when their windpipe is opened by some horrible injury.
- It is accomplished as an inhalation, a strained one, with the throat contracted, or closed with a hole somewhere that is open. It causes alarm.
- Men who can *growl* on demand can usually *wheeze* on demand, and it is just as scary to women and children, but for different reasons, a *growl* being a threat and *wheeze* being an alarm.
- For others, the *wheeze* is involuntary, due to accident or sickness.

> *I know one woman who, after she got past the fear of my purposeful wheeze, wanted to learn how to do it.  Now she can wheeze much higher than I can, women's voices being higher, and all that.  But she can't growl, much as she tried.*

Don't concern yourself with what writers write, they are making a royal mess of the English language. They are hardly an authority, and they commonly misuse words.  And that is separate to the use of the literary device: the purposeful use of incorrect words, to connote something.

Answer (score 49):

**harrumph** /həˈrʌmf/ verb; gerund or present participle: **harrumphing**

> 1. clear the throat noisily
>
>    - grumpily express dissatisfaction or disapproval.
>        "skeptics tend to harrumph at case histories like this"

*He harrumphed and said, ‘I am deeply obliged’.*

(from [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=harrumph%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8))

Comment: "Hey, I didn't get a harrumph out of that guy." According to [*Blazing Saddles*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hey%2C+I+didn%27t+get+a+hrumph+outa+that+guy.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Hey%2C+I+didn%27t+get+a+harumph+out+of+that+guy) it's an agreement made in dissent.

Comment: You don't have to be old to *harrumph* but for lack of a better word, I've abstained.

Comment: @Mazura I don't think anything about this question is limited only to old men, just that it's stereotypically associated with them.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility:

***wheezed his annoyance***

transitive verb
:  **to utter with a sound of wheezing** [breathe with difficulty with a usually audible sibilant or whistling sound ]

> In Darkness Waiting John Shirley - 2013
>
> The **old man wheezed his amusement**. He shifted to accommodate his
>   bags. “You think you workfor yourself, huh?